# Connect MongoDB from remote machine using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have installed Mongodb on one server on port 27017, when I am trying to access the monogdb using c#, it is failing. but able to connect to mongodb that is installed locally 127.0.0.1:27017. From internet I came to know that we need to bind_ip to 0.0.0.0 but did not work, may i have done in wrong way.

Please let know the steps how to connect to remote mongodb using c# or steps to bind ip.

Thanks,
Raj4ms

Comment: please add mongod configuration, thanks

Comment: Using this command I installed service, running under 2017                       
 mongod --dbpath "C:\Mongo\data" --logpath "C:\Mongo\log\mongo.log" --install --serviceName "MongoDB"

Comment: @KOT try adding the `--bind_ip_all` flag to see if that makes any difference. hope you have secured your db before opening it up to the internet. and make sure port 27017 is open/ forwarded to the server machine correctly.

Comment: Tried below commands, but not working,                                                mongod --dbpath "C:\Mongo\data" --logpath "C:\Mongo\log\mongo.log" --bind_ip_all [0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1] --port 27018 --install --serviceName "MongoDB"                                                                                               mongod --dbpath "C:\Mongo\data" --logpath "C:\Mongo\log\mongo.log" --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --port 27018 --install --serviceName "MongoDB"
  mongod --dbpath "C:\Mongo\data" --logpath "C:\Mongo\log\mongo.log" --bind_ip_all 0.0.0.0 --port 27018 --install --serviceName "MongoDB"

Comment: i tried this command: mongod --bind_ip=10.9.84.88:27018, I am able to connect mongo using mongo --host 10.9.84.27018. But when I type show dbs, getting this error: "not master and slaveOk=false" and also using this ip, I am able to connect from Mongo compass but not able to connect from code